# The package name is shown instead of string name

Tags: android, json, listview

The package name is shown instead of string name when i fetch JSON data from web. i think the error are on methods like getItem, getposition,etc   package com.bibek.json;
When i put log the error that is shown is
10-27 15:59:29.914 7611-7611/com.bibek.json V/hari: hehecom.bibek.json.data.SongModel@f515d9d
10-27 15:59:29.964 7611-7611/com.bibek.json V/hari: hehecom.bibek.json.data.SongModel@cc96a4f
10-27 15:59:30.034 7611-7611/com.bibek.json V/hari: hehecom.bibek.json.data.SongModel@f1e15d3

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bibek.json.data.SongModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by User on 10/27/2016.
    package com.example.shailendra.navigaiontab;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    /**
     * Created by Shailendra on 10/19/2016.
     */
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
        TextView textView5;
    private List data;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<SongModel> s) {
            super(context, R.layout.row,s);
            data=s;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object item) {
        return getPosition(item);
    }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater newInflator= LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View customView=  newInflator.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
            String myitem= getItem(position).toString();
            textView5=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.songId);
            // ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


            textView5.setText(myitem);
            Log.v("hari ", "hehe" + myitem);

            return  customView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which information of SongModel would you like to show ?

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`Object#toString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) returns.

If you want to display something else as the result of `toString()`, override the method in your `SongModel` class to return a string representation you want.